# hide modal on when disconnected from internet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I have a helper function  connected(), this function is testing whether a user is online or not. It returns false if offline. I have this ant design modal and I am trying to call this function in the visible prop, in order to hide the modal if the user is not connected. I am not sure I am doing this right. Is it also necessary to put to have  a useEffect ? Any idea on how to achieve this result

```
export const connected = async () => {
    try {
        const on = await fetch('/connection');
        return on.status >= 200 && online.status < 300
    } catch (err) {
        return false 
    }
}


    <Modal
     visible={connected() ? isVisible : false}
     closable={true}
     onCancel={closeModal}
     width={400}
    >
    <p>test</p>
    </Modal>
```

Answer (score 0):

You did it wrong, and let me explain why.

Your function `connected` return promise, and when you working with promises your should either `wait` for the promise to finish, or use the Promise.prototype.then, and Promise.prototype.catch.

Right now your `modal` will be always visible, becuase connected() return a Promise(), not a valid boolean.

To make it work, you can use one of the following methods:

Method 1: using `await`

```
const conntectedValue = await conntected();
```

Method 2: using Promose.prototype`.then()` and `.catch()`

```
let connectedStatus = false;
connected().then(() => {
    connectedStatus = true;
}).catch(() => {
    connectedStatus = false;
})
```

Or you can use `events` to check connectivity.

```
window.addEventListener('offline', (e) => { console.log('offline'); });

window.addEventListener('online', (e) => { console.log('online'); });
```

I hope I explained clearly.

Comment: thanks it makes sense. It helped me a lot. I appreciate how well you explained.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `navigator.onLine`

basic code to check connection status:

```
if (navigator.onLine) {
  console.log('online');
} else {
  console.log('offline');
}
```

link to documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/onLine